# How many $3$-digit numbers have a digit sum of $21$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have the following question:

> How many $3$-digit numbers have a digit sum of $21$?

I can count it by taking separate cases of three digit numbers such that their digit sum is $21$ & by calculating all possible numbers that can be made from each case and by adding them to get the result.

My question: Is there any direct combination formula to calculate this?

(I don't think stars and bars method works here)

Comment: Is this asking about digit sum or something else?

Comment: No count no of such 3-digit numbers exist.

Comment: You want the number of solutions of the equation $h + t + u = 21$ subject to the constraints that $1 \leq h \leq 9$, $0 \leq t \leq 9$, and $0 \leq u \leq 9$.  You can approach this as a [combination with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem subject to those constraints.

Comment: To follow up on @N.F.Taussig comment, notice that none of the digits can be less than $2$, because if one of the digits is a two, the max digit sum is $20$(one $2$ and two $9$'s), so the restraints are $2\le h,t,u\le9$.

Comment: Can I know how to make combination formula out of this?

Answer (score 6):

$$a+b+c=21\implies(9-a)+(9-b)+(9-c)=6$$

Apply stars and bars to $x+y+z=6$ to get $\binom{8}{2}=28$ solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using generating functions: The solution to this problem is equal to the coefficient of $x^{21}$ in the expansion of

$$(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^9)^{2}(x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + x^{9}),$$

which [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=coefficient+of+x%5E%2821%29+in+%281+%2B+x+%2B+x%5E2+%2B+x%5E3+%2B+x%5E4+%2B+x%5E5+%2B+x%5E6+%2B+x%5E7+%2B+x%5E8+%2B+x%5E9%29%5E2+*+%28+x+%2B+x%5E2+%2B+x%5E3+%2B+x%5E4+%2B+x%5E5+%2B+x%5E6+%2B+x%5E7+%2B+x%5E8+%2B+x%5E9%29) says to be $28$.

Comment: Thanks,but is there any way with combination formula?